# SslStream AuthenticateAsServer The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized

Tags: c#, ssl, sslstream

Using c# to communicate via SSL with SslStream.  I am using certificates generated myself and imported into Windows certificate store w/ certlm.msc.  I am getting the following exception "The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized" on SslStream.AuthenticateAsServer().

It seems to work for a little while, but then it stops.  It's been pretty frustrating.  I have read through many articles here but have not found a solution I need to recreate the certificates and import them.  I created the certificates like this:

1. Created a CA:

   > "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64\makecert.exe" ^
   >   -n "CN=CARoot" -r -pe -a sha512 -len 4096 -cy authority -sv CARoot.pvk ^
   >   -ss -sr CARoot.cer
   >
   > "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64\pvk2pfx.exe" ^
   >   -pvk CARoot.pvk -spc CARoot.cer -pfx CARoot.pfx -po Test123
2. Create a Server certificate:

   > "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64\makecert.exe" ^
   >   -n "CN=%1" -iv CARoot.pvk -ic CARoot.cer -pe -a sha512 -len 4096 ^
   >   -sky exchange -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -sv SslServer.pvk SslServer.cer
   >
   > "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64\pvk2pfx.exe" ^
   >   -pvk SslServer.pvk -spc SslServer.cer -pfx SslServer.pfx ^
   >   -po Test123
3. Create a client certificate:

   > "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64\makecert.exe" ^
   >   -n "CN=%1" -iv CARoot.pvk -ic CARoot.cer -pe -a sha512 ^
   >   -len 4096 -sky exchange -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2 -sv SslClient.pvk ^
   >   SslClient.cer
   >
   > "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64\pvk2pfx.exe" ^
   >   -pvk SslClient.pvk -spc SslClient.cer -pfx SslClient.pfx -po Test123

I am basically using the sample code from MSDN, and I put both SslServer and SslClient in my lmhosts file so they resolve.

Note - in Certificate Manager, when i click on them, they say "You have a private key that corresponds to this certificate".

Answer (score 3):

I think I figured it out.  It was a permission issue, I was importing them into localMachine certificate manager (certlm.msc), and after i rebooted machine it didn't work unless I ran my app as admin.  Deleting from there and installing with currentUser Cert Man (certmgr.msc) worked.

Note - I also made certificates a slightly different way, not sure if that mattered:

```
    makecert -ic CARoot.cer -iv CARoot.pvk -n "CN=SslServer2" -sv SslServer2.pvk -pe -sky exchange SslServer2.cer

    cert2spc SslServer2.cer SslServer2.spc

    pvk2pfx -pvk SslServer2.pvk -spc SslServer2.spc -pfx SslServer2.pfx -f
```

Comment: This appears to have resolved it for me too, removing the cert from local machine and installing to current user worked. I assume that it's for development, since we are not running as local system when we run debug from VS.